# How to access dynamic data inside @connect decorator of react-redux-connect?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-router, react-redux

So, I am using react-async-connect in combination with react-redux-connect, as such:

```
@asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({ params, store: { dispatch, getState } }) => {
    if (!isLoaded(getState(), params.userID)) {
      console.log('it was not already loaded')
      return dispatch(loadProfile(params.userID))
    }

    console.log('it was indeed already loaded')

  },
}])
@connect(
  state => ({
    profile: {???},
    error: state.publicData.profile.error,
    loading: state.publicData.profile.loading,
  }),
  { initializeWithKey }
)
export default class Profile extends Component {
  ...etc
```

Basically, the `asyncConnect` fires an action that loads the pertinent data, and then I'm using the @connect decorator to load this data as props for the `Profile` component below. The trouble is, I want to load user profile data into my store based on the userId, so the location of the data is "dynamic". How can I access `params` or other globalState type things inside the @connect decorator?

What I need, supposing the user's id is 1234, is something like this:

```
@connect(
  state => ({
    profile: state.publicData.users.1234,
    error: state.publicData.profile.error,
    loading: state.publicData.profile.loading,
  }),
  { initializeWithKey }
)
```

Of course, that userId is in the `params` object, as well as in the route itself. How can I access this?

**EDIT:**

So I should have looked more carefully at the docs. It turns out you can pass a second `ownProps` argument, like so:

```
@connect(
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    profile: state.publicData.users[ownProps.params.userId],
    error: state.publicData.profile.error,
    loading: state.publicData.profile.loading,
  }),
  { initializeWithKey }
)
```

Comment: If I'm getting you right, you'd like to access route information, which means you need this sort of plugin https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux (if you use react router) that would expose route information into your state tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `router` is not being processed into the state - you should be able to do this in your `reducer.js` file like so:

#### reducer.js

```
...
import { routerStateReducer } from 'redux-router';

export default combineReducers({
  router: routerStateReducer,
...
})
```

This should put all of your router information into the state, and make it accessible to your connect function:

#### component.js

```
@connect(
  state => ({
    profile: state.publicData.users[state.router.params.userId],
    error: state.publicData.profile.error,
    loading: state.publicData.profile.loading,
  }),
  { initializeWithKey }
)
```

This code would assume you have the `userId` and always will, otherwise this won't work.

Also - based on your update - the `ownProps` should have access to the params as well -

```
@connect(
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    profile: state.publicData.users[ownProps.params.userId],
    error: state.publicData.profile.error,
    loading: state.publicData.profile.loading,
  }),
  { initializeWithKey }
)
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not seeing what I need inside the state object there, however somehow the component (when it renders), has a `params` object at its top level, alongside props, which contains the information I need. Any idea what's going on here? If it helps, I'm using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example).

Comment: It may be how the `@connect` decorator is returning everything.  Typically anything I use `@connect` with ends up in props somehow.  Have you, inside `@connect` logged out your full `state`?  I access params using `state.router` all the time - not sure why it's not available, unless the `@async-connect` is removing it.

Comment: Yeah, I've logged out the full state and all that I can see is a `reduxAsyncConnect` object and a `routing` (not `route`) object, which only contains one key: `locationBeforeTransition`...

Comment: K Andrews I am importing that `routing` piece of my store from `'react-router-redux'` directly

Comment: Helps if I look at the boilerplate you are using - you should be able to grab the `router` info from `react-router` in the reducer.

Comment: Actually, just realised I can include ownProps as a second argument to the @connect decorator, I'll update my question above.

Comment: That's also true - was looking at how I have it set up currently and forgot about that as well :)

Comment: @JohnDoe - updated my answer to include both possibilities.